# Finding all relationships from 500 independent variables to 400 dependent variables (time series)

Tags: multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, regularization

I am interested in finding statistically significant relationships from a set of 500 independent variables X (actually about 25 variables + their 25 annual moving average x 10 monthly lags) to a set of 400 possible dependent variables Y (200 + their moving averages). I have about 50 data points which represent monthly data.

What is the best way to go about this?

So far, I have done 200,000 univariate OLS regressions from each X to each Y. Using the Bonferroni correction, I am able to find a number of significant univariate models. How can I go on to multivariate modelling from so many possible variable combinations?

I am mostly interested in solutions that can be implemented in Python.

Comment: The simple answer is: don't go this way... It is wrong and will lead you to false positives and overfitted models.

Comment: Well, for univariates, the Bonferroni part corrects for false positives (my p-value is 10^-47 on 200,000 regressions, so enormously unlikely to be false positive even on 200,000 tries). For multivariates, I imagined that simple models, say bivariates, on 50 datapoints would be fine, keeping Bonferroni standards in mind for significance.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, what do you mean? The X data are economic indicators, the Y data are proprietary industrial data. All numeric, continuous, seasonal (yearly).

Comment: proprietary data from a corporation, that are thought to be correlated with the economy. Think of things like "number of miles driven per capita in a specific month", "number of construction projects started in a specific month", "number of UPS packages delivered this month", etc.

Comment: Why are they not valid? I understand the problem of multiple comparisons and false positives, but this doesn't make the approach invalid, it simply makes the significance bar higher by a factor of n (n models), which some models still easily pass. What do you mean by levels? Do you mean cumulative variables? I am not using that. As for moving averages, are there any smoothing techniques which do not create autocorrelation?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would question why you are just interested in statistical significance. Statistical significance does not necessarily imply an interesting or useful relationship, and in time series analysis there is a particular concern about spurious correlation.

You might first look for trends and seasonality in your original variables (so your 25 X's and 200 Y's) then detrend and deseasonalize each variable. (Some of the significant relationships you found may be based on trends or seasonality). Then you can look at the sample cross-correlation function for each pair of variables. This will give you some guidance concerning which pairs of variables are significant and at what lead or lag.

If you continue to go the uni- / multivariate regression route, I would at least reserve some of the data as a test dataset. Fit the models on the first forty observations and predict your Y's for the remaining ten. Use a measure of the prediction error (e.g. MSE) to assess the predictive power of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the most explanatory models, so I pick the best R-squareds, but statistical significance is of particular importance because I am running so many models, which increases the chance of false positives.